# Which is better to use in Rails model validation: Proc or lambda?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, lambda, proc

I know the difference between proc and lambda. Which is better to use in Rails model validation according to the guidelines: Proc or lambda?

**Proc:**

- Similar behavior as block.
- Can be stored in a variable and be moved around.
- No issue with the number of arguments.
- `return` from a proc would exit the method in which it is called.

**Lambda:**

- Same as Proc, but closer to a method.
- Strict regarding the arguments it gets and it needs.
- `return` from a lambda would exit the lambda, and the method in which it is called would continue executing.

But I haven't seen a validation in which it makes a difference:

```
validates :name, present: true, if: -> { assotiation.present? }
validates :name, present: true, if: proc { |c| c.assotiation.present? }
```

I checked rubocop and didn't find any bits of advice about it. Do you know which is better in the opinion of ruby/rails style guide, rubocop or something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only difference I can think of would be *a possibility* to use early returns from λs. That said, the former would happily validate, while the latter would raise `LocalJumpError`:

```
validates :name, present: true,
  if: -> { return false unless assotiation; assotiation.present? }
validates :name, present: true,
  if: proc { return false unless assotiation; assotiation.present? }
```

Also, I use the following rule of thumb: strict is better than wide-open. So unless it’s absolutely definite that you need a `proc`, λ is the better tool to use *everywhere*.

Comment: Checking the lamba's arity to adjust the arguments being passed, catching the return value in addition to the lambda's result – Rails is probably working hard to make this all possible.

Comment: @Stefan can I pass the argument(s) to validators? I am not _Rails_ guy by any mean and I don’t do _Rails_ (and never been doing,) I really wonder.

Comment: The `if` proc / lambda will be called with the model’s instance as an (optional) argument.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't matter on the real projects :)

for example on my projects I'm doing like this:

```
validates :source, presence: true, if: :validated_source_field?
```

(using method)

Answer (score 1):

From The `Ruby On Rails Guideline`, they tell you to use `Procs`.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-proc-with-if-and-unless

> Finally, it's possible to associate :if and :unless with a Proc object which will be called. Using a Proc object gives you the ability to write an inline condition instead of a separate method. This option is best suited for one-liners.

They don't explicitly tell you why, but based on this article:

https://www.rubyguides.com/2016/02/ruby-procs-and-lambdas/#Lambdas_vs_Procs

and Alekesi's answer, I'm inclined to believe that a `Lambda` would be better in this scenario as it behaves much like a ruby method would.

Honestly, both options are fine.